# VBA: Possibility to search and delete a series in a chart

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a possibility on finding a series in a chart by name and then deleting this specific series.

Comment: If you know the series name, why would you search for the series? Just delete it.

Comment: I have about 650 series in my chart and would like to simplify deleting a specific one by using a macro and therefore the name of the series. Unfortunately, I do not know how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through all `Series` in your `Chart.SeriesCollection` collection, and compare the `Series.Name` with the name you want to delete.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DelChrtSerbyName()

Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim Ser As Series
Dim SerNametoDel As String

SerNametoDel = "MySeriesName" ' change to the name of the series you want to delete

Set ChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1") ' modify to your chart's name

For Each Ser In ChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
    If Ser.Name = SerNametoDel Then
        Ser.delete
        Exit For
    End If
Next Ser

End Sub
```